# Validate a XML against a XSD: Undeclared XSD element

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, delphi-2010

I'm trying to validate a xml against a xsd file but returns de error:

```
1.xsd#/schema/element[1][@name = 'envioLote']/complexType[1]/sequence[1]/element[4]
Undeclared XSD element : '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature'
```

I'm using the following code

```
var
 DOMDocument     : IXMLDOMDocument3;
 ParseError      : IXMLDOMParseError;
 Schema          : XMLSchemaCache;
 sNameSpace      : String;
begin

 DOMDocument                  := CoDOMDocument50.Create;
 DOMDocument.async            := False;
 DOMDocument.resolveExternals := True;
 DOMDocument.validateOnParse  := True;
 DOMDocument.loadXML(sXml);
 Schema := CoXMLSchemaCache50.Create;
 Schema.add( '', 'c:\1.xsd' );
 DOMDocument.schemas := Schema;

 ParseError := DOMDocument.validate;
 Result     := (ParseError.errorCode = 0);
 if not result then      
   showmessage(ParseError.reason);

 DOMDocument := nil; 
 ParseError  := nil;
 Schema      := nil;
end;
```

[1.xsd file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4M8jpzZrtdINmtlQU1KSzAzeE0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="envioLote">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CNPJ" type="TCnpj"/>
                <xs:element name="dhTrans" type="TDataHora"/>
                <xs:element ref="NFS-e" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="500"/>
                <xs:element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="versao" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="NFS-e">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="infNFSe"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="infNFSe">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Id"/>
                <xs:element ref="prest"/>
                <xs:element ref="TomS"/>
                <xs:element ref="det" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="999"/>
                <xs:element ref="total"/>
                <xs:element name="infAdicLT" type="TCodMunIBGE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="infAdicES" type="TSimNao" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="versao" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Id">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="cNFS-e" type="TNumAleatorio"/>
                <xs:element name="mod" type="TModelo"/>
                <xs:element name="serie" type="TSerie"/>
                <xs:element name="nNFS-e" type="TNF"/>
                <xs:element name="dEmi" type="TData"/>
                <xs:element name="hEmi" type="THora"/>
                <xs:element name="tpNF" type="TNFSe"/>
                <xs:element name="refNF" type="TChaveAcesso"/>
                <xs:element name="tpEmis" type="TEmissao"/>
                <xs:element name="ambienteEmi" type="TCharInt"/>
                <xs:element name="formaEmi" type="TCharInt"/>
                <xs:element name="empreitadaGlobal" type="TCharInt"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="prest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CNPJ" type="TCnpj"/>
                <xs:element name="xNome" type="TString150"/>
                <xs:element name="IM" type="TString15"/>
                <xs:element ref="end"/>
                <xs:element name="regimeTrib" type="TCharInt"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="end">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="xLgr" type="TString100"/>
                <xs:element name="nro" type="TString6"/>
                <xs:element name="xBairro" type="TString100"/>
                <xs:element name="cMun" type="TCodMunIBGE"/>
                <xs:element name="xMun" type="TString60"/>
                <xs:element name="UF" type="TString2"/>
                <xs:element name="CEP" type="TCep"/>
                <xs:element name="cPais" type="TcPais"/>
                <xs:element name="xPais" type="TString100"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TomS">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="CNPJ" type="TCnpj"/>
                    <xs:element name="CPF" type="TCpf"/>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="ender"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ender">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="cMun" type="TCodMunIBGE"/>
                <xs:element name="xMun" type="TString60"/>
                <xs:element name="UF" type="TString2"/>
                <xs:element name="cPais" type="TcPais"/>
                <xs:element name="xPais" type="TString100"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="dadosDaObra">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="xLogObra" type="TString100"/>
                <xs:element name="xComplObra" type="TString100" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="vNumeroObra" type="TString15" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xBairroObra" type="TString100" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xCepObra" type="TCep" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="cCidadeObra" type="TCodMunIBGE"/>
                <xs:element name="xCidadeObra" type="TString60"/>
                <xs:element name="xUfObra" type="TString2"/>
                <xs:element name="cPaisObra" type="TcPais"/>
                <xs:element name="xPaisObra" type="TString100"/>
                <xs:element name="numeroArt" type="TString12" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="numeroCei" type="TString12" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="numeroProj" type="TString15" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="numeroMatri" type="TString15" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="transportadora">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="xNomeTrans" type="TString100"/>
                <xs:element name="xCpfCnpjTrans" type="TString15" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xInscEstTrans" type="TString15" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xPlacaTrans" type="TPlacaVeic" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xEndTrans" type="TString100" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="cMunTrans" type="TCodMunIBGE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xMunTrans" type="TString60" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xUfTrans" type="TString2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="cPaisTrans" type="TcPais" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="xPaisTrans" type="TString100" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="vTipoFreteTrans" type="TFrete" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="det">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nItem" type="TOrdemSeq"/>
                <xs:element ref="serv"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="serv">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="cServ" type="TString60"/>
                <xs:element name="cLCServ" type="TLCServ"/>
                <xs:element name="xServ" type="TString256"/>
                <xs:element name="localTributacao" type="TCodMunIBGE"/>
                <xs:element name="localVerifResServ" type="TCharInt"/>
                <xs:element name="uTrib" type="TString2"/>
                <xs:element name="qTrib" type="TDec_1302"/>
                <xs:element name="vUnit" type="TDec_1302"/>
                <xs:element name="vServ" type="TDec_1302"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ISSST">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="vBCST" type="TDec_1302"/>
                <xs:element name="pISSST" type="TDec_0302"/>
                <xs:element name="vISSST" type="TDec_1302"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="total">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="vServ" type="TDec_1302"/>
                <xs:element name="vtNF" type="TDec_1302"/>
                <xs:element name="vtLiq" type="TDec_1302"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ISS"/>
    <xs:element name="Ret">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="vRetIR" type="TDec_1302" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="vRetPISPASEP" type="TDec_1302" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="vRetCOFINS" type="TDec_1302" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="vRetCSLL" type="TDec_1302" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="vRetINSS" type="TDec_1302" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="faturas">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="fat" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="999"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="fat">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nItem" type="TOrdemSeq"/>
                <xs:element name="nFat" type="TNumFatura"/>
                <xs:element name="dVenc" type="TData"/>
                <xs:element name="vFat" type="TDec_1302"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="TCep">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para Codigo Postal</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TCharInt">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para caracter numerico</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TChaveAcesso">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para chave de acesso   </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="39"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TCnpj">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Número do CNPJ</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{14}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TCodMunIBGE">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Código do Município da tabela do IBGE</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{7}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TcPais">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para Codigo do Pais</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{5}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TCpf">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Número do CPF</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{11}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TData">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> Tipo data AAAA-MM-DD</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TDataHora">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> Tipo datetime AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TDec_0302">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Decimal com 5 dígitos, sendo 3 de corpo e 2 decimais</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
            <xs:pattern value="|0|0\.[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{2})?"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TDec_1302">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Decimal com 15 dígitos, sendo 13 de corpo e 2 decimais</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
            <xs:pattern value="|0|0\.[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,12}(\.[0-9]{2})?"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TEmissao">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para forma de emissao  </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[NC]{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TFone">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para numero do telefone  </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="|[0-9]{1,14}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TFrete">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para frete de transportadora  </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="THora">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> Tipo time HH:MM</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
            <xs:pattern value="\d{2}:\d{2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TImpressao">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para formato de impressao   </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
            <!-- Em Caxias uma NFSe somente pode ser impressa no modo retrato  -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TLCServ">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para Lei Complementar 116 </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TModelo">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para modelo de uma NFSe   </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TMotCanc">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para motivo de cancelamento</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TNF">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Número do Documento Fiscal</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,9}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TNFSe">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para uma NFSe   </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TNumAleatorio">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para numero aleatorio </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999999999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TNumFatura">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Número de Fatura em NFS-e</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,3}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TOrdemSeq">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para ordem sequencial de itens </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TPlacaVeic">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo String para placa de veiculo com tamanho maximo 7</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TSerie">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo String de tamanho maximo 3</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TSimNao">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para Sim/Nao  </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[SN]{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TSituacaoCancelamentoNota">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para situacao de cancelamento de uma NFSe </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TSituacaoLote">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para situacao de um lote de NFSe </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TSituacaoNFSe">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para situacao de uma NFSe </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TSituacaoNota">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para situacao de uma nota dentro de um lote submetido </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString2">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 2</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString3">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 3</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString5">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 5</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString6">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 6</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="6"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString12">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 12</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString13">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 13</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString15">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 15</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString50">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 50</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString60">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 60</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="60"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString100">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 100</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString120">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 120</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="120"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString150">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 150</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="150"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TString256">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo para string de tamanho maximo 256</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

[Content of "sXml"](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4M8jpzZrtdIWWM5alFORFFJZWs/edit?usp=sharing)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<envioLote versao="1.0">
    <CNPJ>93120350000172</CNPJ>
    <dhTrans>2013-06-17 16:12:45</dhTrans>
    <NFS-e>
        <infNFSe versao="1.1">
            <Id>
                <cNFS-e>12</cNFS-e>
                <mod>55</mod>
                <serie>S</serie>
                <nNFS-e>12</nNFS-e>
                <dEmi>2013-06-17</dEmi>
                <hEmi>13:48</hEmi>
                <tpNF>1</tpNF>
                <refNF>439312035000017255S00000000012850064870</refNF>
                <tpEmis>N</tpEmis>
                <ambienteEmi>2</ambienteEmi>
                <formaEmi>2</formaEmi>
                <empreitadaGlobal>2</empreitadaGlobal>
            </Id>
            <prest>
                <CNPJ>93120350000172</CNPJ>
                <xNome>CFC ELITRONIC CAR BETA 2 LTDA</xNome>
                <IM>8198</IM>
                <end>
                    <xLgr>RUA X</xLgr>
                    <nro>120</nro>
                    <xBairro>BAIRRO</xBairro>
                    <cMun>4305108</cMun>
                    <xMun>CAXIAS DO SUL</xMun>
                    <UF>RS</UF>
                    <CEP>97015530</CEP>
                    <cPais>01058</cPais>
                    <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
                </end>
                <regimeTrib>3</regimeTrib>
            </prest>
            <TomS>
                <CPF>00295819073</CPF>
                <ender>
                    <cMun>4305108</cMun>
                    <xMun>CAXIAS DO SUL</xMun>
                    <UF>RS</UF>
                    <cPais>01058</cPais>
                    <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
                </ender>
            </TomS>
            <det>
                <nItem>1</nItem>
                <serv>
                    <cServ>10</cServ>
                    <cLCServ>1405</cLCServ>
                    <xServ>AULA PRATICA - CATEGORIA A</xServ>
                    <localTributacao>4305108</localTributacao>
                    <localVerifResServ>1</localVerifResServ>
                    <uTrib>UN</uTrib>
                    <qTrib>20</qTrib>
                    <vUnit>29.95</vUnit>
                    <vServ>599.00</vServ>
                </serv>
            </det>
            <total>
                <vServ>599.00</vServ>
                <vtNF>599.00</vtNF>
                <vtLiq>599.00</vtLiq>
            </total>
            <infAdicLT>4305108</infAdicLT>
        </infNFSe>
    </NFS-e>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>JJtzvD6DJIlwd/ciT6gF1KZl7DA=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>
      DCD5WbABTQpfS8GvmNBBP2+LRUZVWX35fSXA1lX6Thbwf/uyXaD0OdeDhC0Oz6hB5TnqKkUX
      Bgerr7PwUG0/jicrL2V7vTKZ+08DPhU+GwDPgkd8g5jk367rMsUe+rWq70e+98SjWpGNaFZn
      zY1Q7Wqu+uT9DPlDS6hci5Hi5Bg=
    </SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509SubjectName>CN=SB SISTEMAS LTDA:07081093000175, OU=AR SERASA, OU=RFB e-CNPJ A3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, L=MARAU, S=RS, C=BR</X509SubjectName>
                <X509Certificate>MIIGQjCCBSqgAwIBAgIIFHpqkzogjv8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwdTELMAkGA1UE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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</envioLote>
```

I've used this same code earlier without problems, I do not have much experience with xsd, so if anyone can give me a help would be grateful

Comment: The links to your documents don't work. Google Docs fails with too many redirects. Please copy and paste your files directly into your question here on Stack Overflow. If they're too long to share here, then shorten them first. When you've shortened them, make sure they still exhibit the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: +1 thanks for the edit. much better question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says you have an undefined XSD element, and it tells you the element is `Signature` from the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#`. The obvious first step in troubleshooting this problem is to find where that element is defined; if *you* can't find it, you can hardly expect anything else to find it, either.

The namespace where the "missing" element is defined is only mentioned one other place, which is the `xs:import` element. I have just as much experience with XSD as you do, but I can make a pretty confident gues that that element imports definitions from elsewhere, probably from the location given in the `schemaLocation` attribute.

A simple Web search reveals plenty of instances of files named *xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd*, and it indeed defines a type `Signature`.

Evidently, that file needs to be present in order to validate adherence to your schema.

Comment: I put the file xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd in the same folder as my xsd and it worked. thanks

Comment: You could also try calling `Schema.add` a second time to indicate where the XSD for that namespace is. You can give it a path to the file, or you can load the file yourself and pass `add` a `DOMDocument` representing the XSD. Then you don't need to worry about what your current working directory is.